# Generate HTML from Google Sheets, following the same template used by the "publish sheet" option

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a web app that (i) takes a parameter from the URL; (ii) writes this to a cell in Google Sheets (with the side effect of changing most of the data shown in one of the sheets, a dashboard); (iii) generating an HTML version of this new sheet and returning that as the response.

It seems that this approach is flawed --- I'm getting race conditions when multiple people hit the service (they see each other's "personalized" pages), which totally makes sense given how its written. Is there a better / safer approach to this?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?!= include('script_js'); ?>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="data"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

GS:

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .getContent();
}

function doGet(e){
  // get the query "name" parameter and set the default to "World!"
  var name = e.parameter.id || "99999";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var cell = sheet.getRange(1,1);
  cell.setValue(name);

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
  html.setTitle("Your Individual Dashboard");

  return html;
}

function getData(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  return sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();
    }

    function showData(data){
      var html = "";
      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        html += "<br>" + data[i].join(":");
      }
      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = html;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [lock services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service) to prevent multiple access to the sheet by the code.

You will have to modify your `doGet()` code

```
function doGet(e){
  // get the query "name" parameter and set the default to "World!"
  var name = e.parameter.id || "99999";
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  try {
   lock.waitLock(10000);    // try to get a lock for 10 sec else throw error
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dashboard");
   var cell = sheet.getRange(1,1);
   cell.setValue(name);
   SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Apply changes right away.
   var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index")
   // added this line to serve data to the scriplet
   html.data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
   html = html.evaluate()  // evaluate scriplet
   html.setTitle("Your Individual Dashboard");

   } catch (e){   //catch  failure
   var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Server busy, please try again after sometime")

   }
  lock.releaseLock()  // Release lock so that the next person in line can access the code
  return html;
}
```

The lock service in the above code prevents the section of code between `waitLock()` and `releaseLock()` form running concurrently. Thus will prevent a race condition.

Edit: using scriptlets to modify the HTML before serving

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?!= include('script_js'); ?>
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= data[i].join(":") ?></td>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Without trying this, I believe there is still a race condition between when I've written to the sheet (in the GS script), and later when the window.onload handler is called (in the browser). I'm not sure how to move the logic from showData() into the doGet() function -- it may be quite simple, but I'm working via examples and I've not seen any such examples yet. If I could, then both the writing and rendering would be protected by your locking, and it would work quite well. Am I mistaken about this complication (and if I'm not mistaken, any idea how to fix it)?

Comment: You can use [scriptlets] to fix this. Basically, you can modify the sheet and import the data at the same time. That way you do have access the sheet multiple times.

Comment: Modified the code, shouldn't have a race condition now.

Comment: Thanks!  Locking + scriptlets to move the logic works well. A few tweaks in case people are using this as an example somewhere: evaluate s/b evaluate() and createOutput s/b createHtmlOutput.